# Getting error when using async function with react hooks

Tags: reactjs

I am getting following error when I testing hooks with async function;

**Invariant Violation
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]).**

```
async function Test () {
  const data = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/42');
  const json = await data.json();  
  const id = json.id;
  return id;
}
```

...

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>React Hooks Example</h1>

      <Suspense fallback={<LoadingMessage />}>
        <Test />
      </Suspense>

    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/4w2yzvyro7

How can I fix this error

Comment: Where are you using hooks in your code?

Comment: hooks not used I referenced last react proposal as hooks

Comment: Your codesanbox doesn't have async function

Comment: you are returning a promise and it is wrong, you should resolve that promise and then you will have the data. You don't need to await neither `await fetch(...)` and `await data.json()`, what you need to do is `const data = fetch(...)` and then `data.then(yourData => console.log(yourData)`

Comment: *I referenced last react proposal as hooks* - what proposal? The question is misleading. If you have problems with Suspense then hooks are irrelevant. You have obvious problems with Suspense, it's misused. How exactly do you expect `Test` to be rendered? Please, describe it in details, because current implementation is not how Suspense works.

Comment: @estus removing suspence doesnt change anything. I exprect to render 42 under h1

Comment: @estus you can read react-hooks tag for mentioned proposal

Comment: I'm aware of React hooks. The question doesn't use hooks. It's unclear why you mentioned them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<Suspense>` is supposed to be used in very specific manner. It suspends the rendering of `lazy` components and renders other kinds of components as is.

`Test` is not `lazy` component but `async` function, it returns promise object and not React element, hence `Test` is not a valid React component.

`lazy` components are aimed at rendering default imports from lazily loaded components. Basically `lazy` component should return a promise of an object with `default` property that contains valid React component.

It can be used as:

```
const Test = lazy(async () => {
  const data = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/42');
  const json = await data.json();  
  const id = json.id;

  return { default: (props) => <div>{id}</div> };
});

...

<Suspense fallback={<LoadingMessage />}>
  <Test />
</Suspense>
```

Notice that due to its primary use case, `lazy` component can't accept parameters, if `Test` had props, they would be passed to a component that `async` function returns.