# Does React suspense have other use cases apart from code splitting?

Tags: reactjs

Is the only use case for React suspense to use it with lazy loading and code splitting, or are there other use cases such as async data fetching that it is a good fit for?

Comment: react is an huge and very atomic framework which allow developer to perform an unexpected things regarding ui if you want to know more about reactjs and its feature checkout this reactjs bootcamp site [https://reactjs.academy/react-redux-graphql-bootcamp/?gclid=Cj0KCQiA6ozhBRC8ARIsAIh_VC0k4PmUT_FOjlN1GAT88MGZwGXVZoBHvfpy8TNg6o8tWQszrzCiAewaAmzrEALw_wcB]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently `Suspense` supports only `lazy` components. This is subject to change in future.

As shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53836839/3731501), `lazy` can be used with other promises besides `import()`, as long as lazy component returns expected module object with `default` property:

```
const Test = lazy(async () => {
  const data = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/42');
  const json = await data.json();  
  const id = json.id;

  return { default: (props) => <div>{id}</div> };
});

...

<Suspense fallback={<LoadingMessage />}>
  <Test />
</Suspense>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of React, 16.7, lazy loading is the only use case for suspense.

Future versions of React, probably starting with the next major release 17, will allow using it for asynchronous data fetching.

See also:

- [Video of Dan Abramov's talk at React Iceland 2018](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLF0n9SACd4), where he introduces suspense
- [article on React suspense](https://blog.logrocket.com/async-rendering-in-react-with-suspense-5d0eaac886c8).

Answer (score 0):

The benefits of using Suspense include removing the need of a boolean flag denoting the fetching data state, like this.

```
class Something extends Component {
    state = {loading: true}
    componentDidMount() {        
        fetch('https://example.com')
           .then(() => this.setState({loading: false})
    }

    render() {
       if (this.state.loading) return <Loading />
       return <RealData />
    }
}
```

With simple fetching, this will be fine. However, when you have so many async data fetching in different places of the UI, managing the loading boolean will be a mess and the UI can be a little bit janky (you can watch more from this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6g3g0Q_XVb4). With Suspense, you will only need to provide a declarative component to render during loading and all children of Suspense will follow the loading control as the above example.

React suspense will also add the support for async data fetching (currently it is in experimental mode: https://medium.com/@jonatan_salas/a-walk-through-react-experimental-features-562baeb8a63a)

However, with a little hack from this article https://medium.com/@Charles_Stover/react-suspense-with-the-fetch-api-a1b7369b0469, you can use Suspense with async data fetching